# Google Cloud Firewall Rule stuck on 'Updating firewall rule "rule_name"...'

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using a firewall rule to grant access to my Compute Engine instance.
I have been using it for a few years now and all of a sudden, when trying to add a new public ip to the rule set, the message box 'Updating firewall rule "rule_name"...' stays stuck, and even if I see the IP added to the rule set, it does not take effect and the IP is still blocked.

Comment: Hi there! This may be a bug that requieres Google Cloud to take a look. You can report issues to Google using [Report issues and request features with issue trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) page. Do not forget to read the section [What to expect once you've opened an issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#what-to-expect)

Comment: Also, worth asking if you have already tried to perform this operation using an incognito window. Most of the UI issues are related with extensions or browser bugs.

Comment: The notification box usually stays until we click on the cross; however, updated rules not taking effect is strange. Did you try anything different from how you used to do before? Check priorities of rules to ensure no existing higher priority deny rule is blocking your new rules. For detailed investigation, share details about the connection you are trying and whether the use of peering/DNS/shared VPC is involved.